# Making Jquery var to only work if the field is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a Jquery variable to work only when the page hides the field.

In my example I have a page generated by PHP. 
If the user access this page through the destination page, the destination selection on the sidebar is hidden on this php generated page. 
The other way the user can access this page is by clicking on the list link which will show all input fields so they can make their selection.

I want my location_bar variable to only work if they access the page when the destination input field is hidden. Not when they access it through the list link...

Here is my variable and the if else statement related to only that variable.

```
var location_bar = $("hidden input[name='destinations[]']:hidden").val();

if(location_bar <= 0){ ...........
 ........
}else{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.pgtpackages.com/api_courselist.php?page='+ nextPage +'&format=html&destinations%5B%5D='+ location_bar +'',
        success: function(html) {
            is_loaded = true;
            nextPage++;
            if(html){
                jQuery("#infiscroll").append(html);
                jQuery('div#loadMore').hide();
            }else{
                jQuery('div#loadMore').replaceWith("<center><h1  style='color:red'>End of Content !!!!!!!</h1></center>");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I skipped all of the irrelevant code.
Also when I console.log location_bar on the list links I am getting a random value that I did not select.

Comment: Can you show your html? From what I see, your first line should be `var location_bar = $("input[name='destinations[]']:hidden");` and condition should be `if(location_bar.length == 0){`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the result is not `undefined`, for sample:

```
var location_bar = $("hidden input[name='destinations[]']:hidden").val();

if(location_bar != undefined)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.pgtpackages.com/api_courselist.php?page='+ nextPage +'&format=html&destinations%5B%5D='+ location_bar +'',
        success: function(html) {
            is_loaded = true;
            nextPage++;
            if(html){
                jQuery("#infiscroll").append(html);
                jQuery('div#loadMore').hide();
            }else{
                jQuery('div#loadMore').replaceWith("<center><h1  style='color:red'>End of Content !!!!!!!</h1></center>");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You my good sir are a GENIUS... I had to use if(location_bar === undefined)